# MediaWiki and redirecting all non-members

Tags: php, authentication, mediawiki

I built my own login system, and I also have a MediaWiki installed for my members to use. However, I want it only accessible to my members, so I want to redirect all persons who do not pass the session variable check. Where can I place this check? I tried putting it in index.php of MediaWiki, but that does not work for any other part of the wiki then its index.php: `domain.com/wiki/index.php`

Any advice is appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `LocalSettings.php`, it's executed for every request hitting the Wiki.